# Create a mp3 file using System.Speech.dll in WPF

Tags: wpf, mp3, wav

I understand that the SpeechSynthesizer (System.Speech.dll) can be used to convert text to speech. I am working on an application that requires the ability of saving the text as mp3 and wav file.

Is this possible using WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you should be easily able to save to a WAV file via [SpeechSynthesizer::SetOutputToWaveFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms586885.aspx). I don't think there is built-in support in .NET for converting to MP3, but this should be straightforward with the help of a 3rd party library/utility (like [LAME](http://lame.sourceforge.net/)) once you have the audio data as WAV.